# php utf8 encoding

Tags: php, encoding

**i am connecting to a third part tool using soap api.
it accepts only utf8 encoding for the message.**

sometimes I have special characters like `“` and `apostrophe`.
which function best removes it or replaces with the equivalent in `php`.
I am using after setting

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');

function mail_utf8($message) {
    return $message;
}
```

I am also running the string through `urlencode` and `urldecode` functions.

Comment: I think it's better to escape them, as you might need those quotes, so you are still showing them but not messing your code. But I have no experience with soap and don't know what third party tool you are connecting to (maybe you should specify) So wait and see what the experts say

Comment: If you app does not use UTF-8, what is it using instead? (And please stop using random encoding functions, that's not what encodings is about).

Comment: Then make sure you are actually sending it UTF-8 encoded data: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<?php
 $headers   = array();
 $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
 $headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
 $headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
 $headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
 $headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
 $headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
 $headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers));
 ?>
```

Comment: @ i want to just remove or replace all the special characters complied to utf8 encoding...any suggestions for that???

Comment: @VYSHNAVI - Good news! UTF-8 encoding supports **all** characters!

Comment: @rwebduos - Do you think that completely ignoring encoding and treating UTF-8 as ISO-8859-1 will fix anything?

Answer (score -1):

You can remove invalid UTF-8 characters with the following code:

```
$text = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$text);
```